# How to convert * to double/float with pthread, pthread_exit

Tags: c, unix, pthreads, pthread-join, pthread-exit

I need to create a program which calculates recursion (for certain sequence). When I use int and decleare a recursion, that calculates values without floating numbers (like fibonacci sequence, which returns only neutral numbers) it works. However, when trying to use sequences based on divison (with floating numbers) it displays an error as below:

error: cannot convert to a floating type
pthread_exit((void*)(float)wynik;

How should I change the code (or actually a function *ciag, because problem is with that one), that it will accept floating numbers?

Function which works fine (with int)

```
int* fibo(int n){

   int wynik;
   int* n1;
   if (n==0) wynik=0;
   else if (n==1) wynik=1;
   else wynik =(int)fibo((int)(n-1))+(int)fibo((int)(n-2));
   return (int*)wynik;
   pthread_exit((void*)wynik);
}
```

And the one I have problem with (with float, but same happens when I try to use double)

```
    #include <unistd.h>

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define COUNT 2

float *ciag(int n) {
    float wynik;

    if(n == 0)
        wynik = -1;
    else
        wynik = ((float)ciag(n - 1)*(n + 1))/(float)ciag(n - 1)*(float)ciag(n - 1)*(float)ciag(n - 1);

    return(float *)wynik;
    pthread_exit((void *)wynik);
}

void *drugi_watek(void* wynik) {
    int i = 1;  

        while(i == 0) {
        printf("#");
        fflush(stdout);
        usleep(300000);
        pthread_exit((void*)wynik);
    }
}

int main() {
    pthread_t watek_1, watek_2;
    int n;
    float wynik;
    printf("Podaj numer ciagu: ");
    scanf("%d", &n); 

    pthread_create(&watek_1, NULL,(void*)&ciag, n);
    pthread_create(&watek_2, NULL, &drugi_watek, NULL);

    if(!pthread_join(watek_1,(void**)&wynik))
    {
    pthread_cancel(watek_2);
    }

    printf("Element numer %f ciagu: %f\n", &n, &wynik);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly convert a `float` to a `void *` or vice-versa.

The cleanest way to do this is to allocate space for a `float` somewhere -- either from the heap or on the caller's stack -- and have the thread function store the `float` value into the pointed-to variable (`float *` *is* easily convertible to/from `void *`). If you go this route and allocate the value on the stack, you need to make sure that the caller's stack frame remains in existence until the thread completes.

Since the function you want to call is recursive, having it as the thread function is too cumbersome. Better to make it a separate (ordinary) function that takes an `int` argument and returns a `float`. Then make a wrapper function that will be the target for `pthread_create`.

And since you also need to pass an argument `int` to your function, it's easiest to allocate a `struct` to contain both argument and return value (a `union` would also work since you don't really need argument and return value at the same time). Here's a sample program that demonstrates the pattern:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static float ciag(int n)
{
    float wynik;

    if(n == 0)
        wynik = -1;
    else
        wynik = (ciag(n - 1)*(n + 1))/ciag(n - 1)*ciag(n - 1)*ciag(n - 1);

    return wynik;
}

typedef struct {
    int i;
    float f;
} if_t;

static void *ciag_thread(void *vp)
{
    if_t *ifp = vp;
    // Obtain argument from the structure and put the result back into the structure
    ifp->f = ciag(ifp->i);
    return vp;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t watek_1;

    int n = 4;

    // Obtain n however you like. Then place argument into structure allocated 
    // on the stack
    if_t arg;
    arg.i = n;

    // Pointer to structure is implicitly convertible to (void *)
    pthread_create(&watek_1, NULL, ciag_thread, &arg);
    pthread_join(watek_1, NULL);
    printf("Thread returned %f\n", arg.f);
    return 0;
}
```

One other note. Your code seems to suggest that `pthread_join` on the first thread might sometimes fail. That will not happen here. Though for large values of `n`, it may take a very long time to complete, due to the quartic nature of your function.

Comment: This is what I mean. Second thread is supposed to display "#" until sequence is calculcated. Now it works fine :) But - how could I connect it to second thread (which displays "#" and closes when sequence is calculcated)? Thank You for help

Comment: tried this way... https://pastebin.com/qxb7ukuA but still they don't want to connect and work together

Comment: Two options: (1) have your second thread watch a flag variable in its loop (start with the variable at zero, set it to 1 when your first thread finishes); have the second thread exit the loop when it sees the flag set [this method is best because it makes the second thread's shutdown orderly]; (2) Simply use `pthread_cancel` on the second thread when the first one has exited.